# Accessing the data from a Node JS GET request without chaining callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I'm using node.js simply so that I can run scheduled tasks and use GET requests. I'll paste some code that displays what I want to do, although it doesn't work for an obvious reason:

```
const http = require("http");
const request = require("request");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write("Hello, World!");
    let a = getRequest();
    console.log(a);
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);

function getRequest() {
    let b;
    request("http://www.google.com", function(err, res, body) {
        b = body;
    })
    return b;
}
```

So the b from the body does not work due to how the request is asynchronous and this leaves b as undefined when it is eventually printed. I know the way these callback functions are supposed to be used is to keep chaining of the callback function since that's the only place where the contents of `body` can be accessed. However, I don't want to keep chaining off functions because it completely destroys the structure of the program. I want to keep all my node server commands inside the `http.createServer` block. I don't want to place them in functions called from inside the callback function. In this example it doesn't really make sense for the process to be asynchronous since there's only 1 get request anyway and it can't be displayed in console.log until it's received anyway.

I just need a simple way to scrape data with get requests. What would be perfect is if I had some function that I could give a bunch of links, it gets the raw html from them, and then it *waits for them to all be done* so that I can process all the data at once.

How can something like this be implemented in Node.js?

Comment: not exactly sure what you want.  show how you'd solve this with chaining and then perhaps someone can show you how to improve it.

Comment: For example, `console.log(b)` works when inside the callback function but the `console.log(a)` just returns undefined because it is outside of the function. Solving this would  be to move the `console.log` and the `res.end` inside the callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using this module: [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request).
With this module you will be able to make synchronous web requests from your NodeJS code.

Comment: Got to love the disclaimer on that site: _You should not be using this in a production application. In a node.js application you will find that you are completely unable to scale your server. In a client application you will find that sync-request causes the app to hang/freeze. Synchronous web requests are the number one cause of browser crashes. For production apps, you should use then-request, which is exactly the same except that it is asynchronous._

Comment: I know that, but if I understood well your requests run before your HTTP Server. This mean that you can use this module because you're not implementing a sync request in one of your endpoint, so you won't block the execution of your server.